# C# unit test mock method is not working (why?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am testing a controller.

That is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Pmanager.Models;
using RBravoDLL;
using System.Globalization;
using Resources;
using Pmanager.Helpers;

namespace Pmanager.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class GroupController : DefaultController
    {
        private Group m_group;
        public Group p_group
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_group == null)
                {
                    m_group = new Group();
                }
                return m_group;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group = value;
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAdminOperationsOnly]
        public ActionResult NewGroup(Group _group)
        {
            try
            {
                int id_group = 0;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    id_group = p_group.NewGroup(_group);
                }
                else
                {
                    ThrowErrorMessages();
                }
                return Json(new
                {
                    status = "success",
                    title = @Resources.Global.success,
                    text = @Resources.Groups.success_creating_group,
                    messageType = "success",
                    id_group = id_group
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return ErrorHelper(@Resources.Global.error, @Resources.Groups.error_creating_group, err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Resources;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Pmanager.DAL;

namespace Pmanager.Models
{
    public enum Permission
    {
        Not = 0, Read = 1, Analyse = 2, Edit = 3, Admin = 4
    }

    public class Group : IGroup
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool IsOperations { get; set; }
        public Permission? OperationPermission { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }

        public int NewGroup(Group group)
        {
            RioBravoManagerContext ctx = new RioBravoManagerContext();
            ctx.Groups.Add(group);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return group.ID;
        }

        public void UpdateGroup(Group group)
        {
            RioBravoManagerContext ctx = new RioBravoManagerContext();
            if (ctx.Groups.Where(g => g.ID == group.ID).Any())
            {
                Group cgroup = ctx.Groups.Where(g => g.ID == group.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                cgroup.Name = group.Name;
                cgroup.IsOperations = group.IsOperations;
                cgroup.OperationPermission = group.OperationPermission;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Groups.Add(group);
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public interface IGroup
    {
        void UpdateGroup(Group group);
        int NewGroup(Group group);
    }
}
```

The test class is:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Pmanager.Controllers;
using Pmanager.Tests.Helpers;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Pmanager.Models;
using System;
using Moq;

namespace Pmanager.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GroupControllerTest
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer m_serializer;
        ControllerContext m_context;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            m_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            m_context = TestModelHelper.AdminControllerContext();
        }

        public void GroupController_UpdateGroup_Valid()
        {
            // Arrange
            GroupController controller = new GroupController();
            controller.ControllerContext = m_context;

            var _group = new Mock<IGroup>();
            _group.Setup(g => g.UpdateGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Callback((Group group) => { });

            controller.p_group = _group.Object as Group;

            Group _gp = new Group
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Group Name",
                IsOperations = false,
                OperationPermission = Permission.Read
            };

            // Act
            var result = (JsonResult)controller.UpdateGroup(_gp);
            JsonGroup resultFund = m_serializer.Deserialize<JsonGroup>(m_serializer.Serialize(result.Data));

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data, "There should be some data for the JsonResult");
            Assert.IsNotNull(resultFund.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
            Assert.IsTrue(resultFund.status.Equals("success"), "status must be 'success'");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GroupController_UpdateGroup_Invalid()
        {

            // Arrange
            GroupController controller = new GroupController();
            controller.ControllerContext = m_context;
            var _group = new Mock<IGroup>();
            _group.Setup(g => g.UpdateGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Callback((Group group) => { });
            controller.p_group = _group.Object as Group;
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name", @"Missing Name");

            Group _gp = new Group
            {
                ID = 1,
                IsOperations = false,
                OperationPermission = Permission.Read
            };

            // Act
            var result = (JsonResult)controller.UpdateGroup(_gp);
            JsonGroup resultFund = m_serializer.Deserialize<JsonGroup>(m_serializer.Serialize(result.Data));

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data, "There should be some data for the JsonResult");
            Assert.IsNotNull(resultFund.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
            Assert.IsTrue(resultFund.status.Equals("fail"), "status must be 'fail'");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GroupController_NewGroup_Valid()
        {

            // Arrange
            GroupController controller = new GroupController();
            controller.ControllerContext = m_context;

            var _fakegroup = new Mock<IGroup>() { CallBase = false };
            _fakegroup.Setup(g => g.NewGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Returns<Group>((group) => { return 0; }).Verifiable();

            controller.p_group = _fakegroup.Object as Group;

            Group _gp = new Group
            {
                ID = 0,
                Name = "Group Name",
                IsOperations = false,
                OperationPermission = Permission.Read
            };

            // Act
            var result = (JsonResult)controller.NewGroup(_gp);
            JsonGroup resultFund = m_serializer.Deserialize<JsonGroup>(m_serializer.Serialize(result.Data));

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data, "There should be some data for the JsonResult");
            Assert.IsNotNull(resultFund.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
            Assert.IsTrue(resultFund.status.Equals("success"), "status must be 'success'");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GroupController_NewGroup_Invalid()
        {

            // Arrange
            GroupController controller = new GroupController();
            controller.ControllerContext = m_context;
            var _group = new Mock<IGroup>();
            _group.Setup(g => g.NewGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Returns((Group group) => { return 0; });
            controller.p_group = _group.Object as Group;
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name", @"Missing Name");

            Group _gp = new Group
            {
                ID = 1,
                IsOperations = false,
                OperationPermission = Permission.Read
            };

            // Act
            var result = (JsonResult)controller.NewGroup(_gp);
            JsonGroup resultFund = m_serializer.Deserialize<JsonGroup>(m_serializer.Serialize(result.Data));

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data, "There should be some data for the JsonResult");
            Assert.IsNotNull(resultFund.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
            Assert.IsTrue(resultFund.status.Equals("fail"), "status must be 'fail'");
        }
    }

    public class JsonGroup
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<SimpleGroup> groups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is: the mock on the method is not working! It is running the actual method when called. Basically:

```
var _fakegroup = new Mock<IGroup>() { CallBase = false };
_fakegroup.Setup(g => g.NewGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Returns<Group>((group) => { return 0; }).Verifiable();
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: The test code and p_group property in controller don't match up. provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. This example does not even compile with the given information

Comment: I see, I'll do that.

Comment: For starters your IGroup Implementation has too many responsibilities. It That suppose to be a model or a service?

Comment: Just a service, only for testing.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "too many responsibilities"? it has only two methods

Comment: Your classes should have a single responsibility. One reason to change. one common job. The example looks like you are using the Group as both a model/DTO and a service that provides functions/methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes should have a single responsibility. One reason to change. one common job. The example looks like you are using the `Group` as both a model/DTO and a service that provides functions/methods.

Strip functionality out into its own concern.

```
public interface IGroupService {
    void UpdateGroup(Group group);
    int NewGroup(Group group);
}

public class GroupService : IGroupService {

    public int NewGroup(Group group) {
        RioBravoManagerContext ctx = new RioBravoManagerContext();
        ctx.Groups.Add(group);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return group.ID;
    }

    public void UpdateGroup(Group group) {
        RioBravoManagerContext ctx = new RioBravoManagerContext();
        if (ctx.Groups.Where(g => g.ID == group.ID).Any()) {
            Group cgroup = ctx.Groups.Where(g => g.ID == group.ID).SingleOrDefault();
            cgroup.Name = group.Name;
            cgroup.IsOperations = group.IsOperations;
            cgroup.OperationPermission = group.OperationPermission;
        } else {
            ctx.Groups.Add(group);
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Keep models lean. Their sole responsibility should be to hold information to be transferred.

```
public enum Permission {
    Not = 0, Read = 1, Analyse = 2, Edit = 3, Admin = 4
}

public class Group {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsOperations { get; set; }
    public Permission? OperationPermission { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Let the controller depend on the service and inject it via constructor.

```
[Authorize]
public class GroupController : DefaultController {
    private readonly IGroupService groupService;

    public GroupController(IGroupService groupService) {
        this.groupService = groupService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAdminOperationsOnly]
    public ActionResult NewGroup(Group _group) {
        try {
            int id_group = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                id_group = groupService.NewGroup(_group);
            } else {
                ThrowErrorMessages();
            }
            return Json(new
            {
                status = "success",
                title = @Resources.Global.success,
                text = @Resources.Groups.success_creating_group,
                messageType = "success",
                id_group = id_group
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            return ErrorHelper(@Resources.Global.error, @Resources.Groups.error_creating_group, err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Test can not be performed in isolation for the given method under test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GroupController_NewGroup_Valid() {

    // Arrange

    var _fakegroup = new Mock<IGroupService>();
    _fakegroup.Setup(g => g.NewGroup(It.IsAny<Group>())).Returns(1).Verifiable();

    var controller = new GroupController(_fakegroup.Object);

    var _gp = new Group {
        ID = 0,
        Name = "Group Name",
        IsOperations = false,
        OperationPermission = Permission.Read
    };

    // Act
    var result = controller.NewGroup(_gp) as JsonResult;

    // Assert

    _fakegroup.Verify();

    Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data, "There should be some data for the JsonResult");

    dynamic data = result.Data;

    Assert.IsNotNull(data.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
    Assert.IsTrue(data.status.Equals("success"), "status must be 'success'");
}
```

And finally remember to register the service abstraction and implementation with the DI container.

Comment: It worked, thank you.
Except for the last part about the `dynamic data = result.Data;` it says there is no `status` in `data`

Comment: ok that is a whole other topic in itself because you are returning an anonymous object from another assembly. Let me see if I can find a previous post where I answered that.

Comment: never mind, it is definitelly out of scope here, thank you any way :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your properties in the Controller from Type `Group` to `IGroup`.

```
   private IGroup m_group;
    public IGroup p_group
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_group == null)
            {
                m_group = new Group();
            }
            return m_group;
        }
        set
        {
            m_group = value;
        }
    }
```

In the test:

`controller.p_group = _fakegroup.Object;`

This will solve your problem. You're using dependencies as concrete types instead of abstraction(Interface) in the controller.